# c++11: constness in perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11

I created function to detect the constness and l(r)valueness of the argument.

```
template<class T> std::string
detect(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&) {
    return std::string(std::is_const<T>::value ? "const " : "") + "rvalue";
}
template<class T> std::string
detect(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&) {
    return std::string(std::is_const<T>::value ? "const " : "") + "lvalue";
}
```

for some reason, is_const always returns false even on const types, for example const int&.  I tried adding another overload to capture the constness

```
template<class T> std::string
detect(const typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& ) { return "const lvalue"; }
```

compiler then complains that detect is ambiguous when applied to const int&.  So I think the compiler has correct figure out T=const int&, but why doesn't is_const return true?

Comment: How do you call `detect`? `T` in the parameter is in non-deduced context, so it looks like you have to specify it explicitly, e.g. `detect<int>(something)`. Which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: detect is called by a forwarding function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::is_const<T>` only detects top-level `const`. Like `foo const`, or `foo* const`. It doesn't care about "inner" `const`s, like `foo const*` or `foo const&`.

If what you want is to see if type a reference to const, you need to take out the reference first, so the `const` becomes top-level:

```
std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value
```

In any case, the functions shown do not allow type deduction, meaning you have to pass `T` explicitly, like `detect<foo const&>(x)`. Maybe you want something like the following?

```
template<class T> std::string
detect(T&&) { // have T be deduced
    return std::string(std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value ? "const " : "")
         + (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value? "lvalue" : "rvalue");
}
```

Which can be called like `detect(x)`.